# Flat network doesn´t work - Openstack Train

Tags: centos7, openstack

I am following this tutorial: https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/launch-instance-networks-selfservice.html (https://docs.openstack.org/install-gu...) I created the provider network, and the self-service network The self service network is working without any issue (instance gets the internal ip and uses the router to access internet)

If I connect the instance directly to provider network, the dhcp do not works. I can manually assing a public IP address to the instance and it can access internet, but I cant ping the router or any other instance in the same (or other) compute host.

I disabled firewalld. Using centos 7, openstack train release.

Let me try to explain better:
I created the provder network with dhcp enabled:

`openstack network create  --share --external --provider-physical-network provider --provider-network-type flat provider`

`openstack subnet create --network provider --allocation-pool start=X.X.X.101,end=X.X.X.250 --dns-nameserver 8.8.4.4 --gateway X.X.X.1 --subnet-range X.X.X.0/24 provider`

And created the router:

```
openstack router create router
openstack router set router --external-gateway provider
```

ip netns:

```
qrouter-c7fa637e-89bc-4540-9c7a-d890267d176b (id: 2)
qdhcp-54ffc14e-8e9b-42fc-a932-c854ac31876d (id: 1)
qdhcp-19ea13ae-4b2f-4f20-895d-8bbdb266fe88 (id: 0)
```

```
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name | MAC Address       | Fixed IP Addresses                                                             | Status |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| 7b1c9780-2021-4768-ae78-7585825b3b08 |      | fa:16:3e:c7:df:b8 | ip_address='172.16.1.1', subnet_id='30201c79-7d31-4452-b74b-3a06742d4f94'      | ACTIVE |
| bfc6a219-a7f8-4d46-a6e7-6c30b0e4569e |      | fa:16:3e:8c:a7:4f | ip_address='X.X.X.106', subnet_id='65ae3be8-b92b-4b88-80ad-b42822d8a93e' | ACTIVE |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

This is the result after creating the instance:

```
openstack server list
+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name     | Status  | Networks                 | Image | Flavor |
+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+
| 6d0d7fc7-dd07-42e8-affa-27cbe900a7cf | teste4-1 | ACTIVE| provider=X.X.X.X.103 |       | hufe   |
| b5b711c6-e8c5-483d-904a-264bc3a0f08c | teste4-2 | ACTIVE  | provider=X.X.X.101 |       | hufe   |
+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+
```

The problem:
The instances did not get the ip.
If I manually set the ip on the instances, The instance cant ping my router ip (x.x.x.106)
The instances cant ping each other (Ive manually set the ip on both instances)
Both instances can ping my gateway ip (that is outisde openstack infrastructure)
I can ping the router from outsite openstack infrastructure

Can´t find any error in the logs. Does someone have an idea what is happening?

Comment: What is written in your `ml2_conf.ini` of your neutron-server behind `flat_networks` in the section `ml2_type_flat`? And is `type_drivers` in the same file in the section `ml2` set to `flat`?

Comment: From what I know provider networks usually have their own DHCP server, outside of neutron and openstack. In that case you disable dhcp on that neutron subnet and make sure your external dhcp serves requests. Also security-groups always need to be checked.